# getElementsByClassName Help (Uncaught reference error when assigning to variable)

Tags: javascript

Having some trouble selecting class names with plain 'ol vanilla javascript:

```
var email = document.getElementsByClassName('email');
var phone = document.getElementsByClassName('phone');
// Hide phone by default
phone.style.display = "none";

function showContact() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById( "contact-select" );        // Get a reference to the dropdown (select) element
    var selectedItemValue = dropdown.options[ dropdown.selectedIndex ].value; // use the dropdown reference to get the selected item's value

    if ( selectedItemValue === "phone" ) {
        email.style.display = "none";
        phone.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        phone.style.display = "none";
        email.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Keep getting an undefined error anytime I try to call one of the variables. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: When reporting error messages, it is **very** useful to not only give the entire error message, but let us know which line it occurred on.  (Not the line number, that changes, but at highlight the line that had the problem.)

Comment: Sorry - line 4 in this case (and every time the dropdown is changed, triggering the function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

`document.getElementsByClassName` -- Notice that is plural.  It returns an `nodeList` or a `null`.

First step of debugging should have been a `console.log(phone)` and see what value it did have.

Without seeing your markup, I have to take some guesses but try:

```
var email = document.getElementsByClassName('email')[0];
var phone = document.getElementsByClassName('phone')[0];
```

Edit: Returns a `nodeList` which is array-like, but not actually an array.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FHAC40x0 This seems to be a bit closer, but the loop is only effecting one of the elements (which still throws up an error since it is not defined as an array (only `phone` is). Any pointers on that? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Your code, as pasted into jsfiddle, actually works.  Because you have `onload` selected in your framework, it wraps all your Javascript up in a function and hides it away. Change that to `no wrap (head)` and everything works right.

Comment: When I select "phone" from the select element it doesn't change the display - that's the "end-goal" is it doing that on your end?

Comment: Read my last comment, accidently hit return int he middle.

Comment: Oh wow - okay, so almost there -- right now that JS file is in the <head> -- should that be put somewhere else then?

Comment: For that, I'll refer you here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220313/where-should-js-scripts-go-in-an-html-file  In this instance, it doesn't matter a lot.  In other situations, it can.

Comment: Here it is live: http://yhmags.com/contact-widget/ If you view the console, it's throwing up that same error - am I still missing something? I really do appreciate all the help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16674/discussion-between-jeremy-j-starcher-and-zach)

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are doing this in an older version of IE `getElementsByClassName` is not defined so your `email` and `phone` variables are undefined.
2. If this is added to the page before the elements `phone` and `email` are loaded then `email` and `phone` will be undefined.
3. `getElementsByClassName` return a node list so you should actually define `email` and `phone`.

Code:

```
var email = document.getElementsByClassName('email')[0];
var phone = document.getElementsByClassName('phone')[0];
```

**Update**: Or loop through the array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < phone.length; i++)
{
    phone[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Ah very helpful! Any hints on creating that loop to hide those elements based on the `showContact` portion?

Comment: Good catch on `getElementsByClassName` not being defined in IE.  He'll need to know that.

Comment: Yeah definitely helpful - it's the `loop` part I'm trying to research a bit more on now - any pointers on that?

Comment: How to loop a nodeList -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914783/javascript-nodelist

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `nodeList`. You would access it similarly to an array of elements.

#### Edit:

changed to `nodeList`

Comment: nodeList -- not array.  Though they are looped the same way, the difference is important.  I just updated my answer on that.