# Calling two functions from same onclick failure

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem when calling 2 JS functions that work fine separately. I am not well versed in JS: I took the scripts from some posts here and adapted them, and I cannot make them work together. My goal is to make appear the side panel and to change the color of a box within that panel when clicking on the related link in the main text (and to undo it by clicking again on it).

This is the function that I use for showing the side panel:

```
function showRightPanel() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("right-panel");
    if (elem.classList) {
        console.log("classList supported");
        elem.classList.toggle("show");
    } else {
        var classes = elem.className;
        if (classes.indexOf("show") >= 0) {
            elem.className = classes.replace("show", "");
        } else {
            elem.className = classes + " show"; 
        }

        console.log(elem.className);
    }
}
```

And this is the function for changing the color:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('change-color'),
target = document.getElementById('footnotes'),

changeColor = function() {
    target.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('data-color');
};

for(var i=els.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
    els[i].onclick = changeColor;
}
```

And this is the html that calls both functions it:

```
<a href="#footnote1-chapter1" class="change-color" data-color="#E0FFC2"
onclick="showRightPanel();changeColor();"></a>
```

And this is the box that has to appear and change color:

```
<div id="footnotes"><p class="footnote" data-id="footnote1-chapter1">
</p></div>
```

Both scripts are in separate .js files that are referred to in the header, and I know this might be the problem for the second script, as it was mentioned that:

"You should put the javascript at the end of your body (just before ), or wrap it in a function listening load or DOMContentLoaded event (e.g. using addEventListener). If not, document.getElementById is executed before the element is loaded to the DOM, so it return null. – " in this post [change background color of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305080/change-background-color-of-div).

But I do not know how to "wrap it in a function listening load or DOMContentLoaded event".

Can someone please help me?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: In the js you have `els[i].onclick = changeColor;` and in the html you have `onclick="[...]changeColor();"`; you only need one of these.

Comment: You should post your code more completely. I was playing with it a bit, but without seeing what order things are etc, it is tough to help. Have you opened the console and ran your code? There seem to be errors with the JS...

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your code in an on load function, but the general consensus seems to suggest putting your scripts at the end of the body tag instead, according to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220438/2234742) and the [YUI team](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). This accomplishes the same thing as wrapping your code, and might fix your problem if it's related to DOM dependencies.

So I would recommend you put your scripts at the end of your `body` tag instead of in your `head` tag, and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi Maximillian, thank you for your reply. I do not have the scripts in head, only the reference to the external files <script src="js/right-panel.js"></script>, because I would prefer to have cleaner html files. I have tried moving them there, even with the whole scripts and it doesn't solve anything: the panel does not open, it only changes the color.

Answer (score 0):

As Nathan mentioned, your anchor has the attribute onclick as `onclick="showRightPanel();changeColor();"`
But your javascript replaces this attribute, see: `els[i].onclick = changeColor;`
So only changeColor function will be called.

**[update]**

As in the comments, the accepted answer:

```
els[i].onclick = function(){showRightPanel();changeColor.apply(this);}
```

Comment: Hey Rod, I understand what Nathan and you are saying. I would need to change the second script then (as I still need to call the first script in the html), but I don't know how...

Comment: What about `els[i].onclick = function(){showRightPanel();changeColor();};`

Comment: Sorry, since you are using "this" at changeColor function, this will be necessary: `els[i].onclick = function(){showRightPanel();changeColor.apply(this);}`

Comment: Hey Rod, sorry to bother you again, but how can I do it so that the second click on the link changes the background back to the original colour? Thank you again!