# canvas.getContext("2d"); not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the following Error

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at script.js:1

I have tried everything I could think of but nothing works.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("can").innerHTML;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = ("green");
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<!-- Canvas  -->
<canvas id="can" width="300" height="200" style="border:4px solid red;">
</canvas
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your script appears in the document **before** the `<canvas>` element, so when the script runs the canvas is not in the DOM.

Comment: also there's problem here : `</canvas`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should JS scripts go in an HTML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220313/where-should-js-scripts-go-in-an-html-file)

Comment: Another possible duplicate containing useful info (although the first one I linked might be easier for OP to understand): [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: How to approach such issues: Your error says that `getElementById("can")` returns `null`. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), this indicates that "element with the specified ID is not in the document" at the time that method was called. You will then be able to [search on stackoverflow for that specific issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element) and find that your JavaScript must not run before the DOM or rather that specific element has been loaded.

Comment: Do not use .innerHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay there are two serious errors.

1. You're trying to get the element before the DOM is fully loaded. Therefore the `canvas` note is not reachable. See [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
   and [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).
2. Remove `.innerHTML`. [getContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext) appends on the node not on the content.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<!-- Canvas  -->
<canvas id="can" width="300" height="200" style="border:4px solid red;">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

#### 1. Script error when using canvas

> Use `var canvas = document.getElementById("can");`
>
> Not `var canvas = document.getElementById("can").innerHTML();`

See [W3C - Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

#### 2. Add an event listener when the document is ready, then execute your script

See [W3C - DOM Event Listener example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_addeventlistener_dom)

```
function doSomething() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    /*
    another scripts...
    */
}

window.addEventListener('onload', doSomething, false);
```

Comment: Why downvote?  Is my answer to short?  I just write the answer where he makes mistake

Answer (score 2):

There are two things.
First, you don't need .innerHTML as other answers stated.
Second, you either have to run you script at the window load event like so:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = ("green");
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);
});
```

Or you should load the javascript after the canvas tag.